# Insert space when a continuous word is 50 characters long

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I want to cut this string into 50 characters where (after a space) it starts counting up to 50 (excluding spaces), and if the section is over 50 it inserts a space. So far, I can cut it up, but I don't know how to specify "exclude spaces". Tried `[^\s]` but no joy.

```
var str = " http://this.domain.com/fff/222/widget.css http://www.domain.com/myfolder/uploads/1/3/3/7/2332053/custom_themes/8787687678644/more_custom_themes/files/my-main_style.css?8763487634 http://cdn.domain.com/folder/images/thisfolder/common.css?9444"
str.replace(/\s(\w.{50})/g,' $1 ');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = " http://this.domain.com/fff/222/widget.css http://www.domain.com/myfolder/uploads/1/3/3/7/2332053/custom_themes/8787687678644/more_custom_themes/files/my-main_style.css?8763487634 http://cdn.domain.com/folder/images/thisfolder/common.css?9444"
str = str.replace(/([^ ]{50})/g, "$1 ");
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, and I thank **Tyilo** for that. However, **Spudley** put me on the right track with what I ultimately wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If your reason for doing this is to prevent a long string from breeaking out of its area in a browser window, you may want to try the CSS solution:

CSS has a `word-wrap` property, which you can use to tell the browser to break long words even if they don't have a natural break-point.

```
#divwithlongword {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Now if you have HTML as follows:

```
<div id='divwithlongword'>myextraordinarilyandexcessivelylongdomainnamegoeshere.com</div>
```

...it will wordwrap where it needs to within the domain name.

This is supported in all major browsers -- see http://caniuse.com/#search=wordwrap

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh Lord, why have you hidden this from me for so long? Thanks a bunch **Spudley**, this is what I used in the end. Handy to know the regex solution too though, and it was the answer to my question, so I credited **Tylio** for that.

Comment: To whomever suggested the edit "The word-wrap only works on Internet Explorer, support: CSS3, IE5.5.", please add a comment if your edit contradicts the answer.

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 1):

You use the following regex:

```
(\S{50})
```

\S - Matches any character that is not a whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).